# Register Plugins for Android

Tags: cordova

I have a cordova 3.4 project. I alerady added plugins to it like:

```
org.apache.cordova.camera
org.apache.cordova.file
```

and so on. If I deploy the app on my mac via shell:

```
cordova build ios
cordova run ios
```

everythig works fine. If I do the steps on my pc, the app doesn't find the plugins when it's running.

```
cordova build android
cordova run android
```

The android/res/xml/config.xml does look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="de.me.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="Capture">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture" />
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
<feature name="Globalization">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.globalization.Globalization" />
</feature>
<name>UpApp</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

I don't have a specific config.xml file in my cordova/www project folder. Because the xml-file for android and ios is created due to the cordova.build process.

Why isn't android able to find the plugins?

Error-Log:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.device.Device
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 452K, 5% free 9221K/9704K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.getClassByName(PluginEntry.java:117)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:93)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:278)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:232)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
W/System.err﹕ at  com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/apache/cordova/device/Device
W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.cordova.device.Device" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
I/System.out﹕ Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.device.Device.
D/PluginManager﹕ exec() call to unknown plugin: Device
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No, during compilation I don't get any error back.

Comment: Not during compilation, I meant in your JavaScript when you are trying to use the plugins.

Comment: I added the error from the logcat to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the platforms and reinstall them via cli.
The plugins were fine, I didn't have to have a config.xml in my www-folder.
Cordova 3.4 checks the installed plugins and creates a config.xml itself in the appropriated platforms.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the machine you used to install plugin.For example you might have installed it from shell for mac.The plugin might have administrator protection.

I suggest you remove all plugin from your PC and reinstall it via cli.

It will work.I had this issue with my cordova 3.1 project

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with 3.4. I created a new project. Created a new platform, added plugins and build the project. It still can't find the modules.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, without reinstall the platforms. Change this in `platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml`

```
<feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

to

```
<feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
</feature>
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

To make Willy Lee's answer permanent, make the change in `plugins/android.json` instead:

```
"xml": "<feature name=\"File\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils\" /><param name=\"onload\" value=\"true\" /></feature>",
```

to

```
"xml": "<feature name=\"File\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils\" /></feature>",
```

i.e. remove:

```
<param name=\"onload\" value=\"true\" />
```

Any changes in `platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml` will be overwritten when building.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem is bad name of package:

package com.myname.plugins.myplugin; <-- bad

package com.myname.plugins; <--OK!

in "myplugin.java" file.